# Attaching an index of one array to the index of another array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

The idea I'm trying to do is, let's say I have some DOM elements and I want to create a function that accepts 2 arrays, one for the elements and another for the class names. How I make sure that element at index 0 for example only has the class name I pass at index 0 of the other array.

Here is a visual of what I'm trying to do

```js
function addClassName(arrOfElements, arrOfClassNames) {
  // Here is what ive tested
  arrOfElements.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add(arrOfClassNames);
  });
}
```

Expected Result

```js
addClassName([el1, el2], ["class-for-el1", "class-for-el2"]

console.log(el1.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el1"

console.log(el2.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el2"
```

```html
<div class="class-for-el1"></div>
<div class="class-for-el2"></div>
```

What i get instead

```js
console.log(el1.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el1", "class-for-el2"

console.log(el2.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el2", "class-for-el2"
```

```html
<div class="class-for-el1 class-for-el2"></div>
<div class="class-for-el1 class-for-el2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If number of items of arrOfElements and arrOfClassNames is the same, you can do smthing like:

```
function addClassName(arrOfElements, arrOfClassNames) {
  // Here is what ive tested
  arrOfElements.forEach((el, index) => {
    el.classList.add(arrOfClassNames[index]);
  });
}
```

Comment: oh a little trick to go, tysm brother for that hint .. BTW it works even if the arrays arent equal in length. If there are more elements the element that has no corresponding class at its index get "undefined" as class name. On the other hand if classes arr is more than the elements arr, the rest of classes just get ignored

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` callback gives you two parameters, first one being the element itself and second one being its index, you can use this property to achieve what you wanted like this

```js
const el1 = document.getElementById('1'),
    el2 = document.getElementById('2');

function addClassName(arrOfElements, arrOfClassNames) {
    arrOfElements.forEach((el, index) => {
        el.classList.add(arrOfClassNames[index]);
    });
}

addClassName([el1, el2], ['test', 'test1']);

console.log(`class for el1 - ${el1.className}\n`);
console.log(`class for el2 - ${el2.className}`);
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

Comment: no problem :D have fun

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use array `index` to get the class name and add it

```
el.classList.add(arrOfClassNames[i]);
```

**Note:** There are 3 arguments that are passed to the callback function

**1) element:** The `current element` being processed in the array.

**2) index (Optional):** The `index` of element in the array.

**3) array (Optional):** The `array` forEach() was called upon.

```js
function addClassName(arrOfElements, arrOfClassNames) {
  // Here is what ive tested
  arrOfElements.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.add(arrOfClassNames[i]);
  });
}

const [el1, el2] = document.querySelectorAll("div");
addClassName([el1, el2], ["class-for-el1", "class-for-el2"]);

console.log(el1.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el1"

console.log(el2.classList);
// Result: "class-for-el2"
```

```html
<div>First</div>
<div> second </div>
```